# c# keypress listening in background

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Keys key = new Keys();
    while (true)
    {
        if (key == Keys.F5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("F5");
        }
        else if (key == Keys.F4)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("F4");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make this run in the background when the form is out of focus? My ultimate goal is to make this run in the background, and wait for the F5/F4 key to be pressed.

Comment: Do you want to get all keypresses like a keylogger, or do you want a few global hotkeys?

Comment: I added more info to it.  I just want it to run in the background so if I press F5/F4 it would execute a method.  I'm making a dice game tool and F5 will sendkeys some text, specifically "You win!" and F4 will say "Sorry, you lost."

The window would be out of focus and the button_click is just the "start listening" button for the program.

Comment: In that case `RegisterHotKey` is the way to go.

Comment: You can add a KeyDown event to any form of your app, the event just pass unmanaged key events from nested dialogs/forms to its parents until key arrives to the "main" form that do the corresponding action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is. If you want to register a global hotkey you can use the windows api function [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx).
There are already a few questions on SO answering how to use this function in C#.

If you want a hot-key that's only active on a certain control or form you can use the events supplied by WinForms.

If you want to be notifed of all key-presses on the desktop then a low level keyboard hook is appropriate. But don't use a hook if you just want a global hotkey.

Your code itself doesn't make much sense. `new Keys()` just returns the default value of the `Keys` enum(`Keys.None` I guess) which is never equal to <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: He needs to raise an event when a key is pressed on ANY form, even if it is a form with other forms rendering above it as dialogs. I think a solution could be passing unmanaged key events from nested dialogs/forms to its parents until key arrives to the "main" form that do the corresponding action.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the relationship is between the button1 and keypress, but take a look at the [KeyPressEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventhandler.aspx)

Code example below, displays the last key pressed:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(keypressed);
    }

    private void keypressed(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The button1 is the "start listening" button on my windows form.

Comment: I think this only works if the form has focus. And the updated question wants the hotkey to be global.

Comment: Also, KeyPress won't catch Function keys; you need to either use KeyPressUp or ProcessDialogKey.

Comment: it does not answer the question since it was about the background. the wrong answer.